# Abstract Forms using WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, compact-framework

I’m trying to achieve a similar affect in a WinForms application as a master form does with ASP.NET.  My initial thoughts on this were to create a base form and declare it as abstract, but the compiler doesn’t seem to let me do this.

```
public abstract partial class Master : Form
{
    public Master()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

So I have two questions:

- Why will the compiler not let me do this?  Am I using the wrong syntax or is this a genuine restriction.
- Can anyone suggest a workaround or better way to do this?

EDIT:

InitializeComponent code:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.mainMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu();
        this.Menu = this.mainMenu1;
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
        this.Text = "Master";
        this.AutoScroll = true;
    }
```

EDIT:

The error is as follows:

```
The designer must create an instance of type 'Namespace.Master' but it cannot because the type is declared as abstract.
```

Comment: What is the actual compiler error?

Comment: If that is the exact snippet your trying to compile, you'll need to provide a definition for InitializeComponent()

Comment: Perhaps resharper or something complaining about public constructor in abstract class?

Comment: Visual inheritance won't work when you mark the base form class `abstract`. The designer has to be able to initialize an object of that type, and it can't initialize an abstract class. But this shouldn't cause a *compiler* error.

Comment: I've added an edit to indicate the actual error message.  I get the impression that the answer to the first question is that this is a genuine restriction.  Can anyone suggest another way to do this, other than create the Master form as non-abstract?

Comment: It's valid c#, it's not valid in a winforms/designer context. Cody Gray is correct here. The error is there because you have a control on your designer that is marked abstract. Visual Studio attempts to create an instance so that it can render the UI in the designer mode and it throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks all.  In the end, I used the master form idea, but just left it as a concrete form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I’m trying to achieve a similar affect
>   in a WinForms application as a master
>   form does with ASP.NET.

Winforms doesn't really have the concept of a master page.  I imagine your best bet is to use UserControls, and nest your UI composition.

Maybe implement a simple interface like something like to make accessing the sub controls a little easier.

```
public interface IMasterPage
{
 IControlContainer Container { get; }
}
```

Just some thoughts, good luck with your project.

Comment: Agree with this approach.  But for the record it's possible to have a base form class and derive from it, just not as an abstract class.  On .NET Compact Framework projects you must add the DesktopCompatible(true) custom attribute to use the base form and derived ones in the designer.